# Рандомно зависает telegram бот при нажатии на кнопках и не работает remove_keyboard

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть бот-помощник, отвечающий на вопросы. Принцип работы - типа квеста, бот отвечает и выводит новые кнопки. Все работает нормально, кроме 2х моментов:

1. После 10-20 кликов по кнопкам (промежуток в 5 сек) бот виснет минут на 5. В ответе API только false. Зависание происходит рандомно и может произойти на любом шаге. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?
2. Не работает remove_keyboard

Часть кода бота:

```
function get_updates($token) {
    $content = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $update = json_decode($content, TRUE);
    file_put_contents('bot.log', json_encode($content));
    $message = $update["message"];
    return $update;
}
function get_api_url($token) {
    $api_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token;
    return $api_url;
}
function send_message($message, $keyboard = false) {
    global $data;
    global $api_url;
    global $update;
    if ($update['callback_query'])
        $params['chat_id'] = $update['callback_query']['message']['chat']['id'];
    else
        $params['chat_id'] = $data["chat"]["id"];
    $params['text'] = strip_tags($message);
    if ($keyboard !== false) {
        $params['reply_markup'] = json_encode([
            'keyboard' => $keyboard,
            'resize_keyboard' => true,
            'one_time_keyboard' => true
        ]);
    }
    else {
        $params['reply_markup'] = json_encode([
            'remove_keyboard' => true
        ]);
    }
    $result = file_get_contents($api_url.'/sendmessage?'.http_build_query($params));
    file_put_contents('send.log', json_encode($result));
}
$token = "1234";
$update = get_updates($token);
$data = $update['message'];
$api_url = get_api_url($token);
$user_message = $data["text"];
$user = get_user_info();
$callback = $update['callback_query']['data'];
// пример отправки сообщения
if ($user_message == 'текст_кнопки' && /* дополнительные условия */) {
    $message = "сообщение";
    $keyboard = [
        ['1'],
        ['2']
    ];
    send_message($message, $keyboard);
}
```

Comment: уведомления присылаются на https? или сам опрашиваешь каждый раз?

Comment: через вебхук на https

Comment: отлично, он приходит в нужное время? логи вставлял? зависание идет на стороне клиента? или ему просто не приходит месага?

Comment: приходит сразу. в логе просто false вместо json строки. после зависания бот не отвечает ни на одно сообщение. через минут 5 после отправки сообщения ответы на предыдущие нажатия кнопок приходят сразу пачкой

Comment: возможна ли такая ситуация? вы отправляете неправильную команду. приходит false. всё крешится, так как обработка только для json. сервер телеграм от вас не получает ответа, что вы получили сообщение(так как всё упало). он вам отсылает повторно false и так 5-10 раз (там лимит, я не помню точное число). через 5 минут, он помечает это сообщение как bad и прекращает вам его отсылать. после чего пачками приходят накопленные сообщения. возможна такая ситуация? PS Пожалуйста приложите логи. Они очень сильно помогут.

Comment: http://paste.debian.net/931127/
http://paste.debian.net/931128/
похоже приходит не false, а вообще ничего не приходит. file_put_contents туда пулял false, т.к. ничего не приходило и не чего было писать в файл

Comment: сейчас засек время - ровно 5 минут бот не отвечает

Comment: чуть попозже вечером, если не лень будет. у себя подниму и проверю, что там.

Comment: 429 ошибка. бот не отвечает, если отправлено 24 сообщения с промежутком менее 15 сек